# Val_loss & Loss are the same amounts (tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow

Basically my `loss` and `val_loss` are the exact same numbers (0.0585)

Is this a bad or good thing?

Comment: Would you please be more specific? Maybe add more details to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both `loss` and `val_loss` are roughly the same and also if the values are converging then chances are very high that you are doing it right. It indicates perfect-fitting scenario which means that that model is generalising correctly to unseen data, which is a good thing.

Ensure following things:

- Plot the `loss` over time and see if values are converging
- Your `training_data_set` and `val_data_set` are different

Usually your model performs better on the training data than on the unknown validation data. A bit of overfitting is normal, so in ideal scenario what you'll have is:

```
val_loss > loss
```

Eventually your goal should be to make the `val_loss` as low as possible. Some overfitting is nearly always a good thing(`val_loss` being slightly higher than `loss`). All that matters in the end is the `val_loss` as low as you can get it.

Suggest you to do some reading around model overfitting and underfitting if you haven't done that already.

- https://elitedatascience.com/overfitting-in-machine-learning#overfitting-vs-underfitting
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/underfitting-and-overfitting-in-machine-learning/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Ianwhittemore Please upvote the answer so that it can help other folks with similar question on SO